# MakeIndex fails to sort index keys properly

Tags: indexing, sorting

My index does not become ordered correctly:

[image: An incorrectly sorted index]

As you can see, the keyword "fluid" ends up in the beginning of the index instead of right before "fluid flux", where it should be. What can possibly cause this behavior?

Comment: Could you make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and post it. A good way to do so is to make a copy of your file, and then start stripping it down until it exhibits the behaviour you're describing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that there are two possible reasons (at least) for this behavior:

1. An invisible character (like a space) has accedentally been before the first letter of the key, which causes the index key to be sorted differently, or
2. A value that the index key should be sorted by has specified. This can be useful when the index key contains characters which may not have a well defined sorting order but resembles a character that does. (see [Controlling sorting](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing#Controlling_sorting))

In this case, I had accidentally put a space before the index key.

Comment: If you use the `-c` command line option for `makeindex`, leading spaces will be ignored and multiple spaces will be compressed.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks!  (learn something new every day.)  i can think of reasons (that i think are good ones) to want to use explicit multiple/initial/terminal spaces, but if i think some more about the problem, i can probably come up with alternatives, allowing this to be the default.